# Not all functions have to be instantiated?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
namespace RectangleApplication
{
    class Rectangle
    {
        // member variables
        double length;
        double width;
        public void Acceptdetails()
        {
            length = 4.5;
            width = 3.5;
        }

        public double GetArea()
        {
            return length * width;
        }

        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
            Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
            Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
        }
    }

    class ExecuteRectangle
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Acceptdetails();
            r.Display();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When running this C# code the results is:

Length: 4.5
Width: 3.5
Area: 15.75

My newbie questions is:

if you delete either `r.Acceptdetails();` or `r.Display();` then they don't instantiate and the output is not as intended.

So, why does one not have to instantiate `GetArea()` too (`r.GetArea`).

As a newbie I'm trying to understand why some functions have to be instantiated and others not.

Comment: Because that's how you wrote the code to work.  What else do you expect to hear?

Comment: GetArea is local method of class and you are calling it inside class, if you call it from outside class, then you will need to call it using instance

Comment: `GetArea()` is called from within the instance, so it is implied that you are calling `this.GetArea()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are wrong on the very first place. You do not instantiate the functions, you instantiate the class objects. In your code the only instance being made was `new Rectangle()`; of `Rectangle` class. The function are *called* when required.

So in your code, you are calling two (*instance*) functions yourself.

```
r.Acceptdetails();
r.Display();
```

But the other function is being called in the `Display()` function; in the code itself.

```
Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
```

From this line it is clear that you do *call* the function `GetArea()`... Only not in the main function, but instead in another function. If you wanted to call the function yourself, you can change your code as,

```
public void Display()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
   Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
}

// inside the Main function
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.Acceptdetails();
r.Display();
r.GetArea()
Console.ReadLine();
```

#### Alternate code

Also as already mentioned, you can use parameters in constructors also. So your constructor can be like this...

```
// pass the parameters
public Rectangle(double length, double width) {
    // fill the values
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}
```

Leaving the remaining functions as they are (but removing the unnecessary `Acceptdetails()` function), your code would look like this.

```
using System;

namespace RectangleApplication
{
   class Rectangle 
   {
      // member variables
      double length;
      double width;

      public Rectangle(double length, double width) 
      {
          this.length = length;
          this.width = width;
      }

      public double GetArea()
      {
         return length * width; 
      }

      public void Display()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
         Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
      }
   }

   class ExecuteRectangle 
   {
      static void Main(string[] args) 
      {
         Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
         r.Display();
         Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", r.GetArea());
         Console.ReadLine(); 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe by function instantiation you meant function call.

---

> if you delete either "r.Acceptdetails(); or r.Display();" then they
>   don't instantiate and the output is not as intended.

`AcceptDetails` method is assigning values to `Length` and `Width` field. There is no other place in code where you are assigning them any values. Hence when you omit the call for `AcceptDetails`, you will not get the required result.

`Display` method calls `GetArea` method which actually does the calculations.

---

More importantly, you are doing it wrong. Assign values either at the time of object instantiation or in constructor. 
Define a constructor like:

```
public Rectangle(double lengthParameter, double widthParamter)
{
    this.length = lengthParameter;
    this.width = widthParamter;
}
```

and then call it in `Main` method like:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(4.5, 3.5);
r.Display();
```

As a side note, please follow [General Naming Conventions - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for your class fields/properties.